# Python placing input into a for range loop and referring to it in the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say if I want to do

```
num = int(input())
for i in range(num):
    print(num + 1)
```

for example, would it be possible to move input into the same line as the for statement and still refer to it within the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "walrus" [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) `:=` if you're using Python 3.8+:

```
for i in range(num:=int(input())):
    print(num + 1)
```